# Ionic 3 consumir api depois do build

Tags: api, ionic, typescript, ionic3

Seguinte tenho uma api rodando ja, e eu consigo fazer as requisições tranquilamente pelo ionic serve utilizando a extensão do chrome `allow access-control-allow-origin` , e tenho todas as resposta certinho , mas quando dei build no meu projeto pelo `xcode` , e tentei realizar as requisições pelo `xcode`/ `emulador` , com app instalado , não deu certo alguém pode me ajudar oque posso fazer ? para arrumar isto? tipo devo declarar no `xml` alguma coisa?

**meu xml**

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

**meu webservice com a requisição**

```
login(conta: ContaInterface)
{ 
return this.http.post(this.url+'api/userLogin',{
"email": conta.email,
"password": conta.password},{"headers": {'Accept':'application/json'}}); 
}
```

Comment: Tenta debugar pelo Xcode pra ver o erro que tá rolando

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você tenha que liberar o CORS na sua API (no backend).

Se é feita em php vocẽ irá fazer algo do tipo

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Procure sobre como liberar o CORS na linguagem de programação que você escreveu a API.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: @hugocls  ate que a resposta dele me ajudou , pode ser que seja algum problema no meu cors na minha api , mas obrigado